# How to make canvas+custom onscreen keyboard div scale nicely?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have a non-commercial javascript application, here: http://js.irata.online/flex.html that is comprised of a CANVAS to which is rendered an Emscripten application, and a custom DIV below it, which I want to act as an on-screen keyboard.

I would like to be able to cleanly display the canvas tag taking up the majority of the content area, with the keyboard taking up the bottom part of the display.

Thus far, I can get the content area to resize correctly, getting the width/height of the content's flex area, and setting the canvas style width/height to it, but can't seem to get those attributes to set when the canvas tag initially loads and starts its program... urgh.

any thoughts/insights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you're attempting here but if you're looking to do some initial resizing then I'd probably look at the window.onload event

```
window.onload = function(){     
    resizeCanvas(); //replace with your own logic.
};
```